# Why am i getting this error trying to compile an asp.net-mvc app using Parallels on my MacBook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, parallels

I posted a question on the apple site but someone suggested that I might get a better response on stackoverflow directly since its a visual studio related issue.

I installed parallels on my macbook pro and i installed windows 7 iso via a DVD.  at first everything looked fine exception now I am now trying to compile an asp.net-mvc app in visual studio and i get this error over and over

[image]

No matter what i click it will eventually progress but this is quite annoying.  The same question [was asked here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/266164) but no good answer was given.  It almost seems like it think it needs to depend on something from the DVD drive (which it shouldn't)

Can someone please explain why devenv.exe would need the ISO dvd to be connected to my laptop at this point?

Comment: Sorry, Can't help - But, I am working successfully with VS2010 on Win7 & VS2012 on Win8, both running in VirtualBox on my Macbook Air.

Comment: Does the same thing happen for a brand new MVC3 app?

Comment: @rossisdead - yes, i only tried this on a brand new app.  So 1. installed parallels, installed win 7 (from ISO DVD), installed vs 2010 - from web, installed asp.net-mvc4 - from web, create new project, tried to run and got this

Comment: I'm pretty clueless as to what the problem could be. Maybe try putting in an empty disc and find out what files it's trying to access(assuming it'll throw an error about what file it's looking for). Or see if attaching the ISO itself allows for the project to build

Comment: @rossisdead - hmm . . the problem seems to have "gone away" . . i rebooted and now created a new project, compiles and seems fine . . if it doesn't come back in the next few days i will close

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after rebooting this problem seems to go away